# using Spark or pig group by efficient in my use case?

Tags: scala, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-spark, apache-pig

I have a tens of million records, which is customer ID and city ID pair. There are tens of millions of unique customer ID, and only a few hundreds unique city ID. I want to do a merge to get all city ID aggregated for a specific customer ID, and pull back all records. I want to do this using group by customer ID using Pig on Hadoop, and wondering if it is the most efficient way.

Also wondering if there are overhead for sorting in Hadoop (I do not care if customer1 before customer2 or not, as long as all city are aggregated correctly for customer1 and customer 2)? Do you think Spark is better?

Here is an example of inputs,

```
CustomerID1 City1
CustomerID2 City2
CustomerID3 City1
CustomerID1 City3
CustomerID2 City4
```

I want output like this,

```
CustomerID1 City1 City3
CustomerID2 City2 City4
CustomerID3 City1
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just do

```
FOREACH (GROUP data_set BY CustomerId) GENERATE
group as CustomerId,
data.City as City;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer and wondering if there are overhead for sorting in Hadoop (I do not care if customer1 before customer2 or not, as long as all city are aggregated correctly for customer1 and customer 2)? Do you think Spark is better?

Comment: I don't know answer to these questions. I use Hadoop as a client and do not know such details.